# Merging focusrite scarlett inputs into one

Tags: audio-interfaces

I use my focusrite scarlett 2i2 as my main audio interface whenever I use PC. Everything is perfectly fine if I use DAW but I would like to use both inputs in non-DAW environment. For example, Discord (voice communication) only hears first input as does some games I play. Is there a way to use both inputs? Because I want to use mic and some instruments or samplers to have fun while on voice chat.

By the way I think discord used to hear both inputs some time ago. Now it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the scarlett is showing up in Windows.  There are two audio drivers in Windows, ASIO which is used by things like DAWs and provides multi-channel support and Windows Audio which sees individual sound inputs.  These are independent of each other and unless a device has drivers for both, it will not show up in both.

Either an ASIO driver is setting up the binding to the Windows Audio device being used by Discord and the binding got changed (thus changing what is audible in Discord) or the drivers provide one or more Windows Audio devices and the settings in Discord got changed to listen to a different windows audio device.

I would start by looking at what the input device is listed as in Discord and follow the audio path backwards from there.